# Extracting points on linestring based on time since from startpoint (sf)

Tags: r, sf, file-path

I have a series of nodes connected by paths currently imported in `sf`. Each node has a date-time associated with it. For example:

[image]

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

path <- st_as_sf(data.frame(X = c(145, 145.2, 145.8), Y = c(-16, -16.2, -16.5), L1 = 1), coords = c('X', 'Y'), crs = 20353) %>% 
      group_by(L1) %>%
      summarise(do_union = F) %>% 
      st_cast('LINESTRING')

nodes <- st_as_sf(data.frame(X = c(145, 145.2, 145.8), Y = c(-16, -16.2, -16.5), L1 = 1), coords = c('X', 'Y'), crs = 20353) %>%
  mutate(time=seq(as.POSIXct("2020/01/01 12:00:00 UTZ"), as.POSIXct("2020/01/01 13:00:00 UTZ"), by = "30 mins"))

ggplot() + xlim(144.9, 146) + 
  geom_sf(data=nodes) +
  geom_sf(data=path) +
  geom_sf_text(data=nodes, aes(label=time), nudge_y = 0.025)
```

Based on [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76037433/extracting-points-on-linestring-based-on-distance-from-endpoint) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67987924/find-coordinates-x-distance-along-linestring), I've worked out how to sample along the linestring path at known distances from the startpoint using `st_line_sample`, but instead I'd like to identify the point along the path at either a known time, for example at 2020-01-01 12:15:00 AEST (or here 15 minutes since the start-point):

[image]

```
subpath <- st_as_sf(data.frame(X = c(145, 145.1), Y = c(-16, -16.1), L1 = 1), coords = c('X', 'Y'), crs = 20353) %>% 
      group_by(L1) %>%
      summarise(do_union = F) %>% 
      st_cast('LINESTRING')

subnodes <- st_as_sf(data.frame(X = c(145, 145.1), Y = c(-16, -16.1), L1 = 1), coords = c('X', 'Y'), crs = 20353) %>%
  mutate(time=c("2020-01-01 12:00:00 AEST", "2020-01-01 12:15:00 AEST"))

ggplot() + xlim(144.9, 146) +
  geom_sf(data=nodes, size=1.5) +
  geom_sf(data=path) +
  geom_sf(data=subpath, color="red", size=2) +
  geom_sf(data=subnodes, color="red") +
  geom_sf_text(data=(tail(nodes,2)), aes(label=time), color="black", nudge_y = 0.025) +
  geom_sf_text(data=subnodes, aes(label=time), color="red", nudge_y = 0.025)
```

In the above example 12:15 (conveniently) falls halfway between 12:00 and 12:30 in distance, but the full dataset has thousands of points/paths grouped by an id, and requires sampling at random timepoints along each path. I've tried several attempts with `sfnetworks` and `sftracks` packages but I can't find an eloquent or straight forward solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what "eloquent" or "straightforward" means to you, and it would be good to see your solutions that weren't eloquent or straightforward.

This solution does the following: for a given time point, find the first node after the time point, that gives the two nodes that contain the time point (assuming ordering). Compute the fraction of time between those two nodes' time points that the time in question is. Add that fraction of the difference between start and finish to the start coordinate. Return that point. There's also a little test to make it work if the input time is the time of the first node.

```
posat <- function(time, nodes, times){

    next_node = which(times>=time)[1]
    if(next_node==1){ # if time point is first point
      next_node = 2
    }
    prev_node = next_node - 1
    xy = st_coordinates(nodes[c(prev_node, next_node),])
    time_fraction = as.numeric((time - times[prev_node]))/as.numeric((times[next_node]-times[prev_node]))
    st_point(c(
        xy[1,1] + time_fraction*(xy[2,1] - xy[1,1]),
        xy[1,2] + time_fraction*(xy[2,2] - xy[1,2])
    ))    
}
```

Because the above function isn't vectorised over the input vector of times, use `Vectorize` to make a vectorised version:

```
posatv <- Vectorize(posat,"time")
```

For testing lets create a vector of times across your nodes:

```
t = seq(nodes$time[1], nodes$time[length(nodes$time)], len=10)
```

Then the function returns coordinates as a two-row matrix when fed those times, the nodes (for the geometry) and a vector of times (a column from `nodes`):

```
> posatv(t, nodes, nodes$time)
  [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]  [,7]      [,8]
X  145 145.04444 145.08889 145.13333 145.17778 145.26667 145.4 145.53333
Y  -16 -16.04444 -16.08889 -16.13333 -16.17778 -16.23333 -16.3 -16.36667
       [,9] [,10]
X 145.66667 145.8
Y -16.43333 -16.5
```

Flip that round, convert to points, etc etc whatever you need to do:

```
> plot(nodes$geom, axes=TRUE)
> points(t(posatv(t, nodes, nodes$time)))
```

[image]

These are equally spaced time points:

```
> diff(t)
Time differences in mins
[1] 6.666667 6.666667 6.666667 6.666667 6.666667 6.666667 6.666667 6.666667
[9] 6.666667
```

So we can see that the thing speeds up after the middle point.